# Calling simple "Hello World!" function from a compiled C DLL from Python results in OSError: exception: access violation

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, linker

The C code:

```c
// my_module.c

#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
void hello() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}

__declspec(dllexport)
int add_numbers(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

// entry point
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The build script:

```py
# build.py

from setuptools._distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler

compiler = new_compiler()
compiler.compile(["my_module.c"])
compiler.link_shared_lib(["my_module.obj"], "my_module")
```

The main script:

```py
# main.py

import ctypes

my_module = ctypes.CDLL("./my_module.dll")

my_module.add_numbers.argtypes = ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int
my_module.add_numbers.restype = ctypes.c_int

my_module.hello.argtypes = ()
my_module.hello.restype = None

result = my_module.add_numbers(3, 4)
print(type(result), result)

my_module.hello()
```

After running `python build.py` , the dll is created without issues. However, when running `python main.py` , the "add_numbers" function works, but calling the "hello" function results in "OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000002C44".

Am I missing something? Do I somehow need to tell the compiler to include the "stdio.h" header?

Comment: You should tag this windows.  With a few changes (.obj to .o, my_module.dll to libmy_mobile.so, `#define __declspec(...)` ) this works on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems `distutils` is linking the msvc CRT incorrectly.

you shouldn't import anything with an underscore such as `_distutils`, as it is not a part of the public API and you shouldn't use it.

since this is a simple windows dll you could call `cl.exe` directly and compile it. (make sure you open `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022` command prompt before you do)

```
cl.exe /LD my_module.c
```

which will work, but if you have more files then you should probably create a `cmake` project for it and use it to build your C dll from python.

a quick look at the [dependencies](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) of the one generated from `distutils`.

[image]

vs the one from just `cl.exe` directly.

[image]

copying all extra dependencies from the windows sdk to the dll folder should get it to work, but this is not the correct approach.